# d3 line.defined doesn't draw zero value

Tags: javascript, d3.js

fI've made a multiline chart and I want to manage empty values.
I have 2 kinds of empty value '' and ' '
so I use this to map the csv

```
var column = color.domain().map(function(name) {
  return {
    name: name,
    values: data.map(function(d) {
      if(d[name] === '' || d[name] === ' '){
        //if the data is empty I store it in d.vale as a string
        return {name: name, id: d.id, value: d[name]};
      }
      else{
        //if the value is not empty I store it in d.value as number and replacing the coma with a dot (replacedot function)
        return {name: name, id: d.id, value: +replace(replacedot(d[name]))};
      }

    })
  };
});
```

Than inside line.defined I check if d.vale is not a string and if not I return it:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
.defined(function(d) { if(typeof d.value !== 'string'){ return d.value;}})
```

This work fine to escape the empty value, but if there is a 0.0 value in the dataset it is escaped to...

How can I fix it?

Thanks
Daniele

Comment: Have you tried `.defined(function(d) { return (typeof d.value !== 'string'); })`?

Comment: Ok, this works fine! But why my code doesn't work? I don't see so much differences and I don't understand why my more verbose code doesn't work. It depends on the implementation of defined()?

Comment: You're supposed to return true/false. Your code returns a number or nothing (technically null, which gets interpreted as 0).

Comment: I'll also add this as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.defined` function is supposed to return true/false depending on whether the line is defined or not. Your current function returns nothing or a value. It's safer to return true/false explicitly than relying on the correct interpretation of your returned value, i.e. use

```
.defined(function(d) { return (typeof d.value !== 'string'); })
```